# Count with 2 Group by(s) without subquery/CTE

Tags: sql, group-by, count, subquery, sql-date-functions

**--  How many customers placed orders every month?**

**Table: Customer**

[image]

**Desired Output:**

[image]

**My code which gives the desired ouput:**

```
with abc as (select concat(year(order_date),'/', month(order_date)) "date",customer_id
from customer
group by 1,2
order by 1)

select date,count(*) "customers_who_ordered"
from abc
group by 1;
```

**I don't want a subquery or a CTE query. Is there a way I can get the same output in a single query?**

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
select concat(year(order_date),'/', month(order_date)) "date",count(distinct customer_id)
from customer
group by concat(year(order_date),'/', month(order_date))
```